# collecting terms with different order

Tags: differential-equations, algebra

I am using homotopy perturbation method to solve nonlinear ODE.

The first step is to introduce P parameter and collect different order of P.

The code is like this:

```
Collect[(1 - 
 p) ((((1 + 
       De^2 (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
          p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + p^3 Derivative[1][u3])^2)^(
     1/2 (-3 + n)) (1 + 
       De^2 n (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
          p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
          p^3 Derivative[1][u3])^2) (Derivative[2][u0] + 
       p Derivative[2][u1] + p^2 Derivative[2][u2] + 
       p^3 Derivative[2][u3])) (Derivative[1][u0] + 
     p Derivative[1][u1] + p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
     p^3 Derivative[1][u3])) + (1 + 
    De^2 ((Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
        p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + p^3 Derivative[1][u3]))^2)^((
   n - 1)/2) (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
    p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
    p^3 Derivative[1][u3]) (Derivative[2][u0] + 
    p Derivative[2][u1] + p^2 Derivative[2][u2] + 
    p^3 Derivative[2][u3])) + 
  p (-Ha^2 (u0 + p u1 + p^2 u2 + 
    p^3 u3) + (((1 + 
       De^2 (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
          p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + p^3 Derivative[1][u3])^2)^(
     1/2 (-3 + n)) (1 + 

       De^2 n (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
          p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
          p^3 Derivative[1][u3])^2) (Derivative[2][u0] + 
       p Derivative[2][u1] + p^2 Derivative[2][u2] + 
       p^3 Derivative[2][u3])) (Derivative[1][u0] + 
     p Derivative[1][u1] + p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
     p^3 Derivative[1][u3])) + (1 + 
    De^2 ((Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
        p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + p^3 Derivative[1][u3]))^2)^((
   n - 1)/2) (Derivative[1][u0] + p Derivative[1][u1] + 
    p^2 Derivative[1][u2] + 
    p^3 Derivative[1][u3]) (Derivative[2][u0] + 
    p Derivative[2][u1] + p^2 Derivative[2][u2] + 
    p^3 Derivative[2][u3])), p]
```

The problem is that don't get anything back

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that don't get anything back"? I get an output when I run your code. What are you expecting? There are `p`'s still inside brackets because *Mathematica* can't expand `( stuff )^((n-1)/2)` unless you supply an actual integer value for `n`. Is that the issue?

Comment: @march I mean that  I want it to collect expression with p^0,p^1,p^2.

Comment: @march I don't want to give n a value because I need to get a general expression

Comment: *Mathematica* won't do that for you, even if you specify that `n` is an integer (which I assume it is?). Either do this for different actual values of `n` or use `Series` to have *Mathematica* compute a power series in `p` before collecting. This will result in pretty large expressions though.

Comment: @march Is it not surprising that the the input is returned unchanged?  Aren't there plenty of powers of `p` outside of the `(stuff)^(depends on n)` expressions that should be collected?  Compare to e.g. `Collect[(q + p) (1 + p)^n, p]`, which (expectedly) returns `p (1 + p)^n + (1 + p)^n q`.  Another weird thing:  `Collect[OPsExpression, p, foo]` returns a result with `foo` absent.  Compare to e.g. `Collect[a + b, p, foo]`, which (expectedly) returns `foo[a+b]`.

Comment: @march Ah, I finally found the problem.  `Collect[expr ,p]` appears to return `expr` unchanged when `expr` contains a rational function of `p` (other than `p^n_`).  E.g., `Collect[(q + p) (1 + p)^(n - 1), p, foo]` returns its input unchanged.  IMHO, this seems somewhat inconsistent (it carries non-rational functions along, like in `Collect[(1+p) f[p], p]`, and even carries along expressions which will be rational for certain values of the power, like in `Collect[(1+p)(p+q)^n, p]`), but I suppose some choice had to be made.

Comment: @sajad Is `n` an integer?  If so, you can probably apply the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and come up with the coefficients of each power of `p` in terms of `n` and binomial coefficients.

Comment: @jjc385 unfortunately no. The value of n is between 0 and 1

Comment: @sajad I see.  What kind of output are you seeking?

Comment: I think the best solution is to use series and then collect them

Comment: @jjc385. I suspected something of that sort, although admittedly it is a little inconsistent. (It looks like OP needs `Series` anyway, though!)