# How to Collect $x$ powers to group $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}$ together?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have been failing to apply `Collect[#, x]&` to render a like-power series of $x^k$. Here $k = \frac52, \frac32, \frac12,\frac{-1}2$, etc.

The major issue is:

terms like $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x+y}$ are not grouped together even though I thought in `Collect[#, x]&` things like $y$ would be treated as constants. (this can't be fixed by `With`, right?)

For my purpose, $\sqrt{x^5 +y^5}$ is considered the same power as $x^{\frac52}$, and I believe there are no terms like $\frac{\sqrt{x+y}}{\sqrt{x+2y}}$ or $\sqrt{a x^2 + bx}$.

***Question:***

> **How do I arrange the expression (named `myFun` in the code block) into a series of like-powers of $x$? I'd like to group all terms of the form $\sqrt{x+y}$ together, including $y = 1$ and $y=0$.**
>
> (I also would like to see `myFun` in series of like-powers of $L$, where $L$ is another variable shown in the codes. Attempting at $L$-series poses basically the issues.)

**My ultimate goal is to identify the expression as "linear $x$ plus perturbation"** for asymptotic $L$ (actually at just $L \gtrapprox 3$ or 4). Therefore, it is essential that I'll be able to demonstrate the final result as something like "$c_0 + c_1 x +{}$other powers (positive or negative)". Consequently, `Together` or `Collect[#, {Sqrt[x], Sqrt[1+x-y]} }]&` based methods might need to recruit additional tricks to achieve this.

(**Substantial Edit:** Originally the post contained paragraphs about failure of `Simplify` inside `Collect`, which was distracting.)

Mathematically, $x$ and $L$ are the only two variables, and they are  independent. All others are considered parameters with ranges specified in the block.

```
(* WARNING !!! HUGE OUTPUT !!! *)

ClearAll[myFun, tmp, ps (* power sum *), L, x, y, Y, tmp];
ps[j_, M_] := 2/5 ((j + M)^(5/2) - (1 + j)^(5/2)) + ((j + M)^(3/2) + (1 + j)^(3/2))/2 + 1/8 (Sqrt[j + M] - Sqrt[1 + j]) + 1/1920 (1/(j + M)^(3/2) - 1/ ((1 + j)^(3/2)));
tmp = (y (Y + L) - x Y)/(y + Y);
tmp = ps[x, tmp] Sqrt[1/(L + x + Y)] - ps[x - y, tmp] Sqrt[1/(L + x - y)];
myFun = Normal@Series[tmp, {L, \[Infinity], 4}]

(* Collect[ExpandAll@myFun,x,
      Simplify[#, 
        0<x<1 && 0<y<1 && y+Y >0 && L >= 3
    ]&  ] gives many terms that obviously can be combined *)
```

I'm also open to any methods other than `Collect` that produce results similar to what I described above. (This might be a mathematically ill-posed question ... but there seems to be some wiggle room)

My failed attempts thus far include:

(a) Using `Pattern` to try to capture "any sqrt-like function involving $x$", with `BlankNullSequence` which I don't really know how ... `Collect[ myFun, Power[ {___, x, ___ }, _ ] ]` is obviously wrong.

(b) Doing the arrangement on `SeriesData`, that is, without `Normal@`. This gave strange results that I'm not sure how to make use of.

There are some posts about `Collect` but I didn't see any addressing non-integer powers. Others I don't think apply to my situation, like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136611) (esp. the [FAQ therein](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822)) or [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102929).

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

**P.S.**

If the expression seems too large to read, feel free to reduce the order of `Series` from 4 to 3. One can also remove the terms in `ps[j_, M_]` starting at the $+\frac18$ and onward.

Comment: If `expr` is not polynomial in `x`, either `Collect[ expr, x, f]` or `Collect[expr, x]` often simply returns `expr`.  I don't have a reference for this, but I realized it while looking into [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154849/collecting-terms-with-different-order) (see comments).

Comment: Perhaps you might be able to separate your input into pieces that are polynomial in `(x+_)^_`, and then do `Collect[polnomialPart, (x+_)^_, whatever]` on those.  But note e.g. the behavior of `Collect[a Sqrt[x + y] + b Sqrt[x + y] + d (x + y)^(-1/2), (x+_)^_]`, which has head `Times`.

Comment: Finally, you might want to do `Together` on your expression and do `Collect` on the `Numerator` only.

Comment: @jjc385 Thank you for the pattern suggestion `(x+_)^_` with caution. I'll play around with it. I will check on the possible inherent limitation of `Collect`not working for non-polynomials, and maybe I'll modify the post accordingly (remove the `Simplify` issue).  As for `Together`, please see my added clarification in the paragraph starting with the words "my ultimate goal". Anyway your comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just addressing your ultimate goal.  You can do

```
List @@ ExpandAll @ myFun;
Cases[%, #] & /@ {c0_ /; FreeQ[c0, x], x * c1_ /; FreeQ[c1, x]};
split = Plus@@@Append[%, Complement[%%, Flatten@%]];
```

It might be more readable to do

```
{constant, linear, perturbation} = split
```

Check that the split pieces sum to the original expression:

```
Plus @@ split == ExpandAll @ myFun
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Wow this is great! I can understand codes like this when I read it, but I'm not at that level yet to write it myself. This is definitely a big step going in the right direction. It certain helps me a lot to dissect what I'm dealing with. I'll need to do some numerical work to see if this solves all my problems.

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  Were there other parts of your question that I failed  to address?

Comment: No, there weren't. You covered pretty much all aspects of the task in the earlier comments and in this "List then Pattern" approach. Thanks. You help edme realize that I need to have a customized procedure for my specific function and parameter range.